# cordova filetransfer plugin download doesnt show up in image gallery

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have this code that downloads an image from a URL and saves in my phone device but the problem is that it doesnt show up in the image gallery of the phone device rather it shows up in the file storage directory. So, i would like to have it show up in the image gallery.

```
$scope.downloadImage = function(images) {
    var imageName = angular.fromJson(images);
    $scope.$applyAsync(function() {
      $scope.indexchosen === undefined ? $scope.indexchosen = 0 : $scope.indexchosen;
      console.log($scope.indexchosen)
      index = $scope.indexchosen;
      imageToDownload = imageName[index].filename; 
    })

    $scope.$applyAsync(function() {
      window.requestFileSystem(window.LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onSuccess, onError);
    });

    function onSuccess(fileSystem) {
      var directoryEntry = fileSystem.root; 
      countImage+=1; 

      var name = countImage + '-' + imageToDownload.split('/').pop();
      var imageUrl = encodeURI(decodeURIComponent(AppSettings.baseApiUrl + imageToDownload));
      var fp = fileSystem.root.toURL();

      var filepath = fp + '/' + name;
      console.log(filepath)
      var ft = new window.FileTransfer();
      var f =  ft.download(imageUrl, filepath,
        function (entry) {
          $cordovaToast.show("Image Saved", "long", "bottom");
        },
        function (error) {
        }
      );
    }
    function onError(error) {
    }
  }
```

Any help is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If download success, you should re-scan your device storage, because Cordova does not know if the file is downloaded.

so i made a plugin ,

It is a plugin that updates the gallery after downloading.

`https://github.com/pouu69/cordova-plugin-gallery-refresh`

Answer (score -1):

Try to restart your device, and then check your gallery

Comment: i believe tht isnt very efficient for me to tell my users of my app to always restart their device each time to view the images they have just downloaded.

Comment: well this explain why my phone restarts unexpectedly